# How do I enlarge fb profile pic in Ionic without distorting it?

Tags: facebook, vector, ionic2, image-resizing, profile-picture

After I get a user's fb profile pic from the login process. I want to be able to make it to fill the card. No matter what height and width I use, the pic is distorted unless I use it at a very small size. How do I know if my pic is a vector or a raster? I know that when you stretch raster images they distort. there a way to convert the pic into a vector image once I get it from the fb login results?

```
    <ion-item>
      <img src="{{event.hostPhoto}}" height="200" width="100">
    </ion-item>

</ion-card>
```

Comment: Ask Facebook for a 200x200 image.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask fb for the 200 * 150 sized image:

```
facebookConnectPlugin.api('/me?fields=id,picture.width(200).height(150)&access_token=' + authResponse.accessToken, null,
        function (response) {
          info.resolve(response);
        },
        function (response) {
        }
      );
```

Comment: I'm using the Onymos framework which takes care of login for me, so I'm not sure how I would use the code you provided. Is asking facebook for a bigger picture the only way?

Comment: var options = { 
scope: 'public_profile, email' // Facebook comma-separated
};

Comment: you must be specifying what all you need  (for ex. email id or public profile...) so in the same place you can add picture.width(200).height(150) and see if it works.....

there might be another way, but I'm not aware of it

Comment: It doesn't appear to be that straightforward in the Onymos framework. I'll have to look through a few more files. Does anyone else have an idea of what I can do?